# Akka Streams run flow asynchronously

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I have tested simple async flow if it runs asynchronously and I'm suprised it's not. Do I need some additional configuration?

```java
@Configuration
class StreamingConfiguration
{
 
    @Bean
    Materializer materializer(ActorSystem actorSystem)
    {
        return ActorMaterializer.create(actorSystem);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void test(Materializer materializer)
    {
        var takePart = Flow.of(String.class).map(path -> {
            var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 3000) {}
            return path;
        });

        Source.from(Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C", "D"))
            .via(takePart.async())
            .toMat(Sink.fold("", (arg1, arg2) -> arg1), Keep.right())
            .run(materializer)
            .toCompletableFuture()
            .join();
    }
}
```

I can see materializer has default fork-join-pool dispatcher

EDIT: sorry but your example also doesn't work. It takes still 12~ seconds to finish while using `mapAsync`. I tried `flatMapMerge` with the same result : /

```java
   Function<String, CompletionStage<String>> blocking = s -> {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(s);
        };


        Source.from(List.of("A", "B", "C", "D"))
                .mapAsync(4, blocking)
                .toMat(Sink.fold("", (arg1, arg2) -> arg1), Keep.right())
                .run(actorSystem)
                .toCompletableFuture()
                .join();
```

Comment: What exactly would you expect from running asynchronously?  For a stream as simple as the one in the question, there's not going to be any reliably observable difference between `takePart` and `takePart.async()`

Comment: I expect that it takes 3 seconds to complete stream and run each takePart on another thread. Otherwise whats the point in `async()` method? Whats the difference between `takePart` and `takePart.async()` when both runs synchronously?

Comment: @minizibi [this Akka docs page](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-parallelism.html) talks about `async` and when to use it for parallelism. If your `takePart` flow is just supposed to abstract over some long running function, use `mapAsync`. OTOH, if `takePart` is supposed to simulate a more complex flow, take a look at `flatMapMerge` (but your output will be interleaved). In any case, this question is missing more information about what you expect would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka Streams by default materializes stream stages into a single actor: this avoids the overhead of passing messages between stream stages but it does mean that the second element of the stream won't be consumed until the first element has worked its way through the stream.

The `async` operator in a stream means that the stream up to that will be executed in its own actor.  In your example code:

- The `Source` will be an actor
- The `takePart` flow will be an actor
- The `Sink` will be an actor

Each of these will still not allow more than one element to be in process at a time: the gain over not having `async` is that the `Source` and `Sink` can have an element in process at the same time as `takePart` has an element in process.  There's also a small implicit buffer in downstream stages to improve throughput, but that can often be ignored.

In this stream, the `takePart` stage takes 3 seconds to process an element and the `Source` and `Sink` take a few microseconds (for the sake of illustration, we'll say that the `Source` takes 5 microseconds and the `Sink` takes 15 microseconds).  So the rough chronology is (ignoring the buffer):

- time 0: `takePart` signals demand to `Source`
- time 5 us: `Source` emits A to `takePart`
- time 3 seconds + 5 us: `takePart` emits A to `Sink`, signals demand to `Source`
- time 3 seconds + 10 us: `Source` emits B to `takePart`
- time 3 seconds + 20 us: `Sink` processes A, signals demand to `takePart`
- time 6 seconds + 10 us: `takePart` emits B to `Sink`, signals demand to `Source`
- time 6 seconds + 15 us: `Source` emits C to `takePart`
- time 6 seconds + 25 us: `Sink` processes B, signals demand to `takePart`
- time 9 seconds + 15 us: `takePart` emits C to `Sink`, signals demand to `Source`
- time 9 seconds + 20 us: `Source` emits D to `takePart`
- time 9 seconds + 30 us: `Sink` processes C, signals demand to `takePart`
- time 12 seconds + 20 us: `takePart` emits D to `Sink`, signals demand to `Source`, `Source` completes, `takePart` completes
- time 12 seconds + 35 us: `Sink` processes D, completes

Absent the `async`, the stream would complete in `4 * (3 sec + 20 us)`, so the `async` saved 45 us (cumulatively, `async` in this stream would save 15 us for every element after the first), so not much of a gain.  A pipelined stream at full utilization has throughput gated by the slowest section (you can imagine a highway where the speed limit drops: if the traffic is heavy enough to saturate the highway, the speed on the highway before the speed limit drop will be the speed limit after the drop): you get the best results if each side of the `async` processes elements at about the same rate.

There is, somewhat confusingly, another usage of "async" in the Akka Streams API, used to denote stages which communicate with asynchronous processes by obtaining `Future`s (Scala) or `CompletionStage`s (Java): the process completing the `Future`/`CompletionStage` may run on a different thread, and the stream stage often includes some limit on the number of `Future`s/`CompletionStage`s it will allow to be in flight at a time.  `mapAsync` is an example of this.

In Scala (I am generally unfamiliar with the Java future APIs), this would be something like (ignoring setting an implicit `ExecutionContext`, etc.):

```
def blockOnElement(e: String): Future[String] = Future {
  Thread.sleep(3000)
  e
}

Source(List("A", "B", "C", "D"))
  .mapAsync(4)(blockOnElement)
  .runWith(Sink.fold("") { (acc, _) => acc })
```

In that, assuming sufficient (more than 4) threads in the dispatcher, the entire stream should finish (assuming the 5/15 us delays above) in about 3 seconds and 80 us (the `Source` and `Sink` will still combine to spend 20 us on every element.

In addition to @Alec's mention of `flatMapMerge`, it's often useful to run a substream in `mapAsync` by using `Source.single` and `Sink.head`: the materialized value of the sink will be a `Future`/`CompletionStage` of the output element and the `mapAsync` will in turn preserve ordering downstream (in contrast to `flatMapMerge`).

Comment: I have added 2nd example, which also doesn't run in parallel, seems like identical to yours.

Comment: In your second example, you're sleeping before constructing the future, thus blocking the thread/actor running the `mapAsync` stage.  But, given a way to run a task in a threadpool and then complete a future with the result of that task (which is what the Scala `Future { }` does), you'll get the asynchrony.

Comment: Yeah, I just created a small project in Scala to run your case and that's the point. So basically akka-streams does not run anything in parallel by self. We have to create Threads / working pool by ourselves anyway

Comment: From a quick glance through the javadoc, something like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.Executor) looks likely to be helpful.

Comment: `actorSystem.executionContext()` is an executor (i.e. a threadpool you can use with `CompletableFuture.runAsync`

Comment: Actually scratch that, `supplyAsync` better matches the shape.... it looks like a lambda can be a `Supplier`.  And now I know more about Java asynchrony than I did yesterday :)

Comment: Yup, I'm familiar with java api. I was convinced that akka is creating new threads for us, what was wrong. Thanks for comprehensive answer.

Comment: Akka does create its threadpool, which you can get through the actor system... by default it's not great for blocking I/O, but it's often fairly useful.